# Combine Multiple Queries into One

Tags: sql

i have a stored procedure having above 3000 lines of code as below. its a validate business rules proc. There are similar queries for different columns from different tables. i dont know how do i combine these queries together so i can shrink this proc down. the query below is part of that proc and there are many similar queries for each column and their respective tables.  i am using SQL Server 2005.

```
INSERT INTO
            [Elig].[dbo].[ErrorTable]
            (
             [SeqId],
             [CodeId],
             [SubjectArea],
             [FieldName],
             [TableName],
             [ErrorValue],
             [ActiveFlag]
            )
            SELECT
                [sd].[SubscriberDataId] AS [SeqId],
                @InvalidLength AS [CodeId],
                @SubjectArea AS [SubjectArea],
                'FacetsGroup' AS [FieldName],
                'Facets.SubscriberData',
                [sd].[SubscriberFirstName] AS [ErrorValue],
                @ActiveFlag AS [ActiveFlag]
            FROM
                [Facets].[SubscriberData] [sd]
            WHERE
                ISNUMERIC([FacetsGroup]) = 0  and
                NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM Elig.dbo.ErrorTable 
                            WHERE TableName = 'Facets.SubscriberData'
                            AND FieldName = 'FacetsGroup'
                            AND ErrorValue = [sd].[FacetsGroup])
```

Comment: Any reason why you want to compact SP?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the query above. What do you mean with "combine" these queries?, there seems to be just one query.

Comment: i am just wondering that 3000 lines code shouldnt affect the performance.

Comment: Hi @Lamak, the query doesnt have any problem. I have so many queries like this in one stored proc but just wodnering if i could combine all of them in one.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have queries inside loops, it is usually a bad idea to combine multiple queries into one. First, the queries might have distinct sets of columns so you'll have to find a way to union these. Second, larger queries tend to confuse optimizer so you are much more likely to have performance problems with one large query than with smaller ones. In a sense you are swimming against the current that is the "*divide and concur*" idiom.